# How to draw an 8x8 square on an image?

Tags: php

I have an image: image.png (could be jpg or gif)

How can I draw an 8x8 square at `$x, $y` and then save the image to `$file`?

Comment: php imagick! pass the image path to a new imagick instance, draw the rectangle, writeImage, done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for [`imagerectangle()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagerectangle.php):

```
// Load the image
$img = imagecreatefrompng("image.png"); // or imagecreatefromjpeg(), etc.

// Set a colour for the sides of the rectangle
$color = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255); // for a white rectangle

// Draw an 8x8 recangle at coordinates ($x, $y) from top left
imagerectangle($img, $x, $y, $x+8, $y+8, $color);

// Or, use imagefilledrectangle() with the same arguments if you want it filled

// Save the image
imagepng($img, "image.png"); // or imagejpeg(), etc.
```